Switching per environment in apphosting.yaml doesn't work well
I'm using Firebase AppHosting to host Next.js.
In order to switch the contents of apphosting.yaml depending on multiple environments, I am creating apphsoting.stg.yaml with reference to the official document below, but as far as I can see from the build log, apphsoting.yaml is being read.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-hosting/multiple-environments
Is there anything else I need to do other than what is described in this document?
My Setting

Did you manage to resolve this issue? I'm experiencing the same problem and would appreciate any insights.

I still haven't solved it either. I've contacted Firebase support, so I'll share if there's any progress.

Hi @anaminkumamoto I have the exact same issue. In the build log I see: Missing apphosting config at /workspace/apphosting.yaml, using reasonable defaults
